# SOAP сервер. org.apache.ws.commons.schema.XmlSchemaException: Schema name conflict in collection

Tags: веб-сервер, soap, config, xsd, wsdl

При запуске Spring Boot приложение крашится с такой ошибкой. Почему-то возникает конфликт схем в коллекции.

Создание бинов:

```java
@EnableWs
@Configuration
public class WebServiceConfig extends WsConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean messageDispatcherServlet(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        MessageDispatcherServlet servlet = new MessageDispatcherServlet();
        servlet.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        servlet.setTransformWsdlLocations(true);
        return new ServletRegistrationBean(servlet, "/employee/*");
    }

    @Bean(name = "employeeDetails")
    public DefaultWsdl11Definition defaultWsdl11Definition(XsdSchemaCollection employeeSchemaCollection) {
        DefaultWsdl11Definition wsdl11Definition = new DefaultWsdl11Definition();
        wsdl11Definition.setPortTypeName("EmployeePort");
        wsdl11Definition.setLocationUri("/employee/employee-details");
        wsdl11Definition.setTargetNamespace("http://service.server.jaxws.baeldung.com/");
        wsdl11Definition.setSchemaCollection(employeeSchemaCollection);
        return wsdl11Definition;
    }

    @Bean
    public XsdSchemaCollection employeeSchemaCollection() {
        ClassPathResource resource1 = new ClassPathResource("xsd/employee1.xsd");
        ClassPathResource resource2 = new ClassPathResource("xsd/employee2.xsd");
        return new CommonsXsdSchemaCollection(resource1, resource2);
    }
}
```

Полный стек трейс ошибки

```
2019-12-11 17:49:55.221  INFO 31135 --- [           main] c.j.JaxWsSpringServerApplication         : Starting JaxWsSpringServerApplication on sambalinskipc with PID 31135 (/home/sambalinski/Documents/Projects/Other/soap-test/employee/jax-ws-spring-server/target/classes started by sambalinski in /home/sambalinski/Documents/Projects/Other/soap-test/employee/jax-ws-spring-server)
2019-12-11 17:49:55.223  INFO 31135 --- [           main] c.j.JaxWsSpringServerApplication         : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2019-12-11 17:49:55.894  INFO 31135 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'webServiceConfig' of type [com.jaxwsspringserver.WebServiceConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$12d175e7] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2019-12-11 17:49:55.899  INFO 31135 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.DelegatingWsConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.DelegatingWsConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f206bc50] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2019-12-11 17:49:55.941  INFO 31135 --- [           main] .w.s.a.s.AnnotationActionEndpointMapping : Supporting [WS-Addressing August 2004, WS-Addressing 1.0]
2019-12-11 17:49:56.108  INFO 31135 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2019-12-11 17:49:56.117  INFO 31135 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2019-12-11 17:49:56.117  INFO 31135 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.29]
2019-12-11 17:49:56.184  INFO 31135 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2019-12-11 17:49:56.184  INFO 31135 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 930 ms
2019-12-11 17:49:56.301  WARN 31135 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'employeeDetails' defined in class path resource [com/jaxwsspringserver/WebServiceConfig.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'defaultWsdl11Definition' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'employeeSchemaCollection' defined in class path resource [com/jaxwsspringserver/WebServiceConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.xml.xsd.commons.CommonsXsdSchemaException: Schema [class path resource [xsd/employee2.xsd]] could not be loaded; nested exception is org.apache.ws.commons.schema.XmlSchemaException: Schema name conflict in collection. Namespace: 
2019-12-11 17:49:56.303  INFO 31135 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2019-12-11 17:49:56.313  INFO 31135 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2019-12-11 17:49:56.319 ERROR 31135 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'employeeDetails' defined in class path resource [com/jaxwsspringserver/WebServiceConfig.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'defaultWsdl11Definition' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'employeeSchemaCollection' defined in class path resource [com/jaxwsspringserver/WebServiceConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.xml.xsd.commons.CommonsXsdSchemaException: Schema [class path resource [xsd/employee2.xsd]] could not be loaded; nested exception is org.apache.ws.commons.schema.XmlSchemaException: Schema name conflict in collection. Namespace: 
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:798) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:539) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:879) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:878) ~[spring-context-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) ~[spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) ~[spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at com.jaxwsspringserver.JaxWsSpringServerApplication.main(JaxWsSpringServerApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'employeeSchemaCollection' defined in class path resource [com/jaxwsspringserver/WebServiceConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.xml.xsd.commons.CommonsXsdSchemaException: Schema [class path resource [xsd/employee2.xsd]] could not be loaded; nested exception is org.apache.ws.commons.schema.XmlSchemaException: Schema name conflict in collection. Namespace: 
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1796) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1287) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1207) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:885) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:789) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.xml.xsd.commons.CommonsXsdSchemaException: Schema [class path resource [xsd/employee2.xsd]] could not be loaded; nested exception is org.apache.ws.commons.schema.XmlSchemaException: Schema name conflict in collection. Namespace: 
    at org.springframework.xml.xsd.commons.CommonsXsdSchemaCollection.afterPropertiesSet(CommonsXsdSchemaCollection.java:149) ~[spring-xml-3.0.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1855) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1792) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    ... 30 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.ws.commons.schema.XmlSchemaException: Schema name conflict in collection. Namespace: 
    at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.SchemaBuilder.handleSchemaElementBasics(SchemaBuilder.java:1488) ~[xmlschema-core-2.2.4.jar:na]
    at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.SchemaBuilder.handleXmlSchemaElement(SchemaBuilder.java:648) ~[xmlschema-core-2.2.4.jar:na]
    at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.SchemaBuilder.build(SchemaBuilder.java:156) ~[xmlschema-core-2.2.4.jar:na]
    at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.XmlSchemaCollection.read(XmlSchemaCollection.java:508) ~[xmlschema-core-2.2.4.jar:na]
    at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.XmlSchemaCollection.read(XmlSchemaCollection.java:716) ~[xmlschema-core-2.2.4.jar:na]
    at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.XmlSchemaCollection.read(XmlSchemaCollection.java:564) ~[xmlschema-core-2.2.4.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.xml.xsd.commons.CommonsXsdSchemaCollection.afterPropertiesSet(CommonsXsdSchemaCollection.java:140) ~[spring-xml-3.0.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
    ... 32 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Если я создаю бин с одной схемой:

```
    @Bean
    public XsdSchemaCollection employeeSchemaCollection() {
        ClassPathResource resource1 = new ClassPathResource("xsd/employee1.xsd");
//        ClassPathResource resource2 = new ClassPathResource("xsd/employee2.xsd");
        return new CommonsXsdSchemaCollection(resource1);
    }
```

То приложение нормально запускается.

Вот мои xsd файлы:

1.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<xs:schema targetNamespace="http://service.server.jaxws.baeldung.com/" version="1.0"
           xmlns:tns="http://service.server.jaxws.baeldung.com/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:import schemaLocation="employee2.xsd"/>
    <xs:element name="EmployeeAlreadyExists" type="tns:EmployeeAlreadyExists"/>
    <xs:element name="EmployeeNotFound" type="tns:EmployeeNotFound"/>
    <xs:element name="addEmployee" type="tns:addEmployee"/>
    <xs:element name="addEmployeeResponse" type="tns:addEmployeeResponse"/>
    <xs:element name="countEmployees" type="tns:countEmployees"/>
    <xs:element name="countEmployeesResponse" type="tns:countEmployeesResponse"/>
    <xs:element name="deleteEmployee" type="tns:deleteEmployee"/>
    <xs:element name="deleteEmployeeResponse" type="tns:deleteEmployeeResponse"/>
    <xs:element name="getAllEmployees" type="tns:getAllEmployees"/>
    <xs:element name="getAllEmployeesResponse" type="tns:getAllEmployeesResponse"/>
    <xs:element name="getEmployee" type="tns:getEmployee"/>
    <xs:element name="getEmployeeResponse" type="tns:getEmployeeResponse"/>
    <xs:element name="updateEmployee" type="tns:updateEmployee"/>
    <xs:element name="updateEmployeeResponse" type="tns:updateEmployeeResponse"/>
    <xs:complexType name="addEmployee">

        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="arg0" type="xs:int"/>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="arg1" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="addEmployeeResponse">

        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="return" type="tns:employee"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="employee">

        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="firstName" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="id" type="xs:int"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="countEmployees">

        <xs:sequence/>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="countEmployeesResponse">

        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="return" type="xs:int"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="deleteEmployee">

        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="arg0" type="xs:int"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="deleteEmployeeResponse">

        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="return" type="xs:boolean"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="EmployeeAlreadyExists">

        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="exception">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="message" type="xs:string"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="EmployeeNotFound">

        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="exception">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="message" type="xs:string"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="getAllEmployees">

        <xs:sequence/>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="getAllEmployeesResponse">

        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="return" type="tns:employee"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="getEmployee">

        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="arg0" type="xs:int"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="getEmployeeResponse">

        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="return" type="tns:employee"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="updateEmployee">

        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="arg0" type="xs:int"/>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="arg1" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="updateEmployeeResponse">

        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="return" type="tns:employee"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

2.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<xs:schema version="1.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:complexType name="exception">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="throwable">
                <xs:sequence/>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="throwable">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="stackTrace" nillable="true" type="stackTraceElement"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType final="extension restriction" name="stackTraceElement">
        <xs:sequence/>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Ругается на второй xsd файл. Я его импортировал в первом (подсвечивается зеленым цветом и он кликабельный, то есть он его видит)

Answer (score 0):

Похоже, что дело в том, что не нужно добавлять зависимые друг от друга xsd файлы, поэтому и возникает конфликт имён. Добавлять нужно только основной.

В моём рабочем проекте 2 группы xsd файлов:
В первой группе 7 xsd файлов зависимых друг от друга
Во второй группе 2 xsd файла, зависимых друг от друга

В конфиге, при создании бина я добавлял по одному основному xsd файлу из каждой группы,
и программа запускалась без конфликта имён.

Answer (score 0):

Поменяйте местами схемы. `CommonsXsdSchemaCollection` зависит от порядка добавления схем.